# Add manually a PDF page on the toc

Tags: table-of-contents, pdf

I'm new to the language and I need to add some PDF pages on my LaTeX document.
I added with the command `\includepdf[pages=...]{MyFile.pdf}`.
Now, the problem is that those pages need to be added to the table of content. I tried  `\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Subs_name}` but it doesn't increment the first PDF page number.
Here's a snippet of my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\title{Reti e Sicurezza}
\author{Luca Polese}
\date{Settembre 2020 - Gennaio 2021}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage

\part{Lezione 1: Introduzione}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Introduzione}
\includepdf[pages=1]{Reti e Sicurezza.pdf}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Introduzione alle Reti/Classificazioni}
\includepdf[pages=2]{Reti e Sicurezza.pdf}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Classificazioni 2}
\includepdf[pages=3]{Reti e Sicurezza.pdf}

\part{Lezione 2:}

\end{document}
```

The problem here is that the output on the table of content is:
[image]

The number of the subcontent should be:

```
Introduction .................................. 4
Introduction/Classification of networks ....... 5
Classification of networks .................... 6
```

Can you please help me?
Thanks in advice

Comment: I think you might benefit from including a compilable example of your document. We can't see what is affecting your output (for example in the preamble) so it's hard to tell what the problem might be.

Comment: @Plergux code added. I thought it would have been useless

Comment: Maybe so, but we can't tell that without seeing it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\includepdf` takes the option `addtotoc={page number, section, level, heading, label}`

So you can do:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Lesson 1: Introduction}
\includepdf[pages=-,addtotoc={
            1, subsection, 1, Introduction, L1:1,
            2, subsection, 1, Introduction/Classification of networks, L1:2,
            3, subsection, 1, Classification of networks2, L1:3}]
{Network.pdf}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution and I guess it's the right one, but can you please help me with that? I think I'm messing around with something. Thx